# Space between items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView, which I fill with items (ImageView + TextView from another layout) via an Adapter. The problem is that the distance between two items changes depending on the text. I would like that the space between all the items was always the same. How can I achieve this?

Here a picture reflecting the problem:

[image]

Here the xml containing my recyclerView:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categoryRecycler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_category" />
```

Here the xml for an item:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_appliance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:text="name category"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/categoryImage" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as long as you have added 100dp as max width why not set the width of the text to 100dp instead of wrap_content or you can set a fixed width to your `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Certainly, It would be better idea to set width as 100dp

Comment: or just set a fixed size to the ConsteraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when the text has a size below `100dp` the item will have a lower width

The image has a width of 60dp with margins set to 0dp in this configuration, the layout was a `minWidth` of 60dp

When the TextView increases in width past 60dp the item width will increase as well

To fix this you could increase the margins of the image, or you can follow @Shay Kin advice and set the width to 100dp directly.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_appliance" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:text="name category"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/categoryImage" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```